# App Store Connect API to download Financial Reports (c#)

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to download financial reports through the App Store Connect API.

My client is C# and I have managed to authenticate and connect to the API. I have hit the following endpoint - which I would expect is for the May 2023 report.

[https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/financeReports?filter[regionCode]=Z1&filter[reportDate]=2023-05&filter[reportType]=FINANCE_DETAIL&filter[vendorNumber]=123456789](https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/financeReports?filter%5BregionCode%5D=Z1&filter%5BreportDate%5D=2023-05&filter%5BreportType%5D=FINANCE_DETAIL&filter%5BvendorNumber%5D=123456789)

(from the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_finance_reports)

When I download the file, extract it from the .GZ archive and then open it , the Start Date is showing 02/05/2023 and the end date is showing 03/04/2023. The transaction and settlement dates look wrong also (first line is 02/20/2023 and 02/21/2023).

When I download the May file directly from the Apple Connect website, I am getting Start Date 05/07/2023, end date 06/03/2023. First line of data shows 05/21/2023, 05/25/2023

Any thoughts on what is going on here? is there some issue with the URL? I can't see an obvious error.

Comment: Please have a look at the Apple's fiscal calendar

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=fiscalcalendar

The report that you are getting will be in accordance with the Apple's fiscal calendar.

Comment: Have checked it already - seems some issue with the API call - odd that a May 2023 report from the API is brining back results from Feb; but the May 2023 report from the Website is brining back from May